# How to build an IoT system with mobile app using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, sensors

My project is to develop an IoT system that uses sensors to collect data which can be monitored by the user using a mobile app. I want to use AWS for this project but since I am a beginner, I am confused on where to start. Do you have some tips or some chronological steps that I have to learn and do to be able to create this project?

Answer (score 0):

Not a criticism, but an observation. If you don't know the conceptual steps to achieve this, understand this before you jump into any technology. If you can't do this right now without any AWS technology, jumping in with AWS is going to make your life 100x harder.

Break it down into key challenges.

1. IoT Sensors. Start with a single sensor. Build a POC with a Raspberry PI that sends data from the device to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
2. Build a listening service on your localhost. i.e. HelloWorldIoTDevice simply responds with a 200 OK, don't worry about the data and payloads right now
3. Save this to a database that simple shows 200 OK messages every time a successful message is received from the IoT device
4. Build a HelloWorldWebApp that reads this data from the database
5. Build an API that reads the data from the database
6. Build a HelloWorldMobileApp that reads data from the API
7. Build it in full - Add payloads, add authentication and authorisation, get a POC published on the web so it works end to end
8. Productionise it

Then you need to get actual data flowing. Conceptually this is a relatively simple thing. But in reality this requires an extremely in-depth understanding of technology layers across the entire stack which is extremely challenging if you are a beginner as this is an enormous learning curve.

Take a look at Ngrok to help with building these types of POCs, https://www.contradodigital.com/2016/04/09/access-localhost-internet/

Hope that provides a bit of guidance. Take one step at a time.